# Why Do IP Forwarding Tables Have a Gateway Field?

Tags: networking, ip

An entry in an IP forwarding table specifies both an interface and a gateway. Why is the gateway needed? No matter what, once you've picked the right forwarding entry to use to forward your packet, you're going to send your packet out the interface that forwarding entry specifies reagrdless of what value is in its gateway field.

**Example**

In this example, assume all netmasks are 255.255.255.0 for the simple, common case.

My IP address is 104.4.10.2, and I rely on the machine with IP address 104.4.10.1 to handle traffic I want to send to 104.4.40.X. The interface that connects me to 104.4.10.1 is named "eth1". My forwarding table will have this entry:

```
Destination     Netmask           Interface     Gateway  
===========     =============     =========     =======
104.4.40.0      255.255.255.0     eth1          104.4.10.1
```

If I want to send a packet to, say, 104.4.40.5, I'll bitwise and that IP address with the above forwarding entry's netmask of 255.255.255.0, get 104.4.40.0 as a result, see that this forwarding entry matches, and send the packet out eth1. I never even used the fact that there is a gateway of 104.4.10.1 as part of this forwarding entry.

So, I want to ask... Why is there a gateway field in a forwarding table entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a local network route, the Gateway column (sometimes called Next Hop) might be blank or might contain the IP address of the interface on that network segment.

For a remote network route, the Gateway (Next Hop) column is the IP address of a local router located between the node and the remote network.

Comment: Both of your statements are correct. But even in the case of a remote network, I didn't make use of the gateway (next hop) field when selecting the forwarding entry to use.

Comment: @Dave If I'm understanding you correctly, you bitwise to see if the rule applies and the gateway is used after that by the router, to route your packets.

Comment: Yep, I do a bitwise and to see if the rule applies. But the second half of your sentence doesn't quite line up. You speak of the gateway and the router as if they were different things, but the router *is* the gateway. And that fact is called out by the "Gateway" field of the forwarding table entry. While not inaccurate, I don't see how it's useful. I never use that field when *deciding* or *acting*: I use the destination and the netmask when *deciding* to use the forwarding table entry, and I *act* by sending the packet out the interface specified by the forwarding entry.

Comment: @Dave the ip of the gateway is used to find out the MAC address of the next-hop, so that the datagram that go out of your eth1 can be tagged with the next-hop physical address.